# Label counter position in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build the following gif and is almost done however, the counter is out of the axis and it doesn't show properly. The problem is that I do not know how or where to change either the position of the counter or increase the x-axis.
Any help? I post the full code with the data retrieved and additional charts.
Thanks in advance for your time.

```
 library(quantmod)
 library(viridis)
 library(scales)
 gdp = getSymbols('CLVMNACSCAB1GQES',src='FRED', auto.assign=F)
 gdp.df = data.frame(date=time(gdp), coredata(gdp) )
 library(data.table)
 dt<-data.table(gdp.df)
 dt[,year:=year(date)]
 dt.y<-dt[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=year ]
 dt.y[,gdp.g:=CLVMNACSCAB1GQES/shift(CLVMNACSCAB1GQES,1,fill=NA)-1]
 library(tidyverse)
 ggplot(data=dt.y,aes(x=date,y=CLVMNACSCAB1GQES))+geom_line()+
     scale_y_log10(label=scales::comma,breaks=c(160000,180000,220000,260000,320000))+
  theme_minimal()+theme(plot.caption=element_text(hjust=0))+
   labs(x="",y="",title="GDP growth",
   subtitle="Annual average, log scale",
   caption="Source: U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis via St Louis  Fed FRED database")
 ggplot(data=dt.y,aes(x=date,y=gdp.g))+geom_col()+
 scale_y_continuous(label=scales::percent)+
  theme_minimal()+theme(plot.caption=element_text(hjust=0))+
  labs(x="",y="",title="GDP growth",
   subtitle="Percent change",
   caption="Source: U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis via St Louis Fed FRED database")
 library(animation)
 library(tweenr)
 myf<-function(y){
 dt2<-copy(dt.y)[year>1995 & year<2017]
 dt2<-dt2[year > y ,gdp.g:=0]
 dt2$yearf<-factor(dt2$year)
 dt2$p<-factor(round(dt2$gdp.g*100,1))
 dt2$y<-factor(y)
 return(as.data.frame(dt2))
  }
 my.list2<-lapply(c(2016,seq(1996,2016,1)),myf)
 tf <- tween_states(my.list2, tweenlength= 2, statelength=3, 
               ease=rep('cubic-in-out',200), nframes=240)
 tf<-data.table(tf)

 oopt = ani.options(interval = 0.1)

 saveGIF({for (i in 1:max(tf$.frame)) {
 g<-ggplot(data=tf[.frame==i],
       aes(x=year,y=gdp.g,frame=year,fill=gdp.g,color=gdp.g))+geom_col()+ geom_text(data=tf[.frame==i & yearf==y,],x=2010,y=0.06,
          aes(label=paste(yearf,":",p,"%")),family="Arial Black",size=14,alpha=0.75)+
    scale_color_viridis(option="D",end=0.9)+
    geom_col(data=dt.y[year<2017 & year>1995,],alpha=0,color=NA)+
   theme_minimal()+scale_fill_viridis(option="D",end=0.9)+scale_y_continuous(label=percent)+
labs(x="",y="",title="GDP percent change previous year",
      caption="Source: U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis")+
      theme(plot.caption=element_text(hjust=0),
       plot.title=element_text(face="bold",size=14),
       plot.subtitle=element_text(face="italic",size=12),
      legend.position="none")
     print(g)
     ani.pause()
    print(paste(i,"out of",max(tf$.frame)))
     }
     },movie.name="Spain GDP growth.gif",ani.width = 840, ani.height =450)
```

Comment: Most probably this has nothing to do with GIF. Retagged.

Comment: Probably. In any case, it's been solved. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If the problem has been solved, then please post your answer (since [it\`s perfectly normal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own posts) for the benefit of all others who have the same question.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that. I just modified the "x" and "y" coordinates in the line: "aes(x=year,y=gdp.g,frame=year,fill=gdp.g,color=gdp.g))+geom_col()+ geom_text(data=tf[.frame==i & yearf==y,],x=2010,y=0.06,..." by "x=2011, y=0.04"